# Diffeomorphic image of $D^n$ and existence of isotopy of $\Bbb R^n$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Suppose $f:\Bbb R^n\rightarrow \Bbb R^n$ is a diffeomorphism. Let $D^n$ be the disk of radius $1$ centered at the origin.

My question is, is there an isotopy $g:\Bbb R^n\times I\rightarrow\Bbb R^n$ such that $g(\cdot,0)\upharpoonright D^n$ is the identity and $g(\cdot,1)\upharpoonright D^n$ is an homeomorphism onto $f(D^n)$.

If this does not hold, does it hold for the open ball centered at the origin instead?

Answer (score 2):

Assume without loss of generality that $f(0) = 0$. Then $f$ is isotopic to a linear map via $F_t(x) = f(tx)/t$, and the result for $F_0$ follows from the fact that $\pi_0 GL_n(\mathbb{R}) = \{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: Is $t \in [0,1]$? What's $F_0$ supposed to be? Generally the way you show the uniqueness of the isotopy class of the disk is by contracting along a radial vector field until the map is well enough approximated by its derivative.

Comment: We're in the $C^1$ category, so $F_0$ is well-defined (or, at least, $F_t$ extends from $(0, 1]$ across $0$ uniquely). You can instead proceed by, say, using a tubular neighborhood argument to construct an isotopy between a linear function and $F_t$ for sufficiently small $t > 0$, but that seems like overkill in this case.